# Magento product sort order using an attribute

Tags: magento, sorting, custom-attributes

I'm developing a website in magento.

Now I'm trying to order the display of my products in a particular order.

For this I have added an attribute named 'display_order' and linked to the attribute set(general). Then I have manually added the order in each of my products.

These are the codes i used. My products are having different attribute sets.

First one

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$_productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('display_order', array('gt' => 0));
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
```

Second one

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$_productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$_productCollection->addAttributeToSort('display_order', 'ASC');
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
```

I'm getting the products in sorted order but there is a minor issue, It's sorting only based on the a similar attribute set.

ie; product with same kind of attribute set with sort first and then it will sort other products with same attribute set and so on..

So I'm not getting the order correct in the order of the 'display_order'

Is there a way to get it exactly in the order which I have given without considering in which attribute set the product resides.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

--
Tibin Mathew

Answer (score 4):

The default way in Mangeto to change the product display order is by going to:

1. Catalog > Categories > Manage Categories
2. Click the category you want to edit on the left hand column.
3. Click the Category Products tab on the right hand column.
4. Change your sort order here.

[image: Reference]

Comment: This is correct. But this will work only with a single category. If my products is in different categories this will not work.

Comment: @tibinmathew didn't realise that since your question didn't state it. Seems like you'd have to override the core Magento functionality so that `addAttributeToSort()` does not group the products by attribute sets. This could cause bugs in other areas though, in my opinion.

Comment: I thought Tibin was talking about the frontend, not the backend... because I'm looking for adding a frontend sorting option too :)

Answer (score 0):

For Front-end use this code,Here i created custom attribute "product_sort_order".

```
$website_id = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId();
$storeId =  Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();            
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
   ->setStoreId($storeId)
   ->getCollection() 
   ->addAttributeToSelect('*') 
   ->addWebsiteFilter($website_id)
   ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'simple'));
$collection->getSelect()->limit(6);
$collection->addAttributeToSort('product_sort_order', Varien_Data_Collection::SORT_ORDER_DESC);
```